# Label and text not aligning properly on text overflow in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an inline label and readonly text. When readonly text overflows it goes under the label. I would like text to not go under label.

This is what i am getting:

[image: incorrect overflow]

Where as i would like:

[image: ok]

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4 class="text-muted">Employer Information</h4>
                <div class="form-inline word-wrap">
                    <label class="control-label label-normalWeight">Name</label>
                    <strong><bean:write name="myform" property="name" /></strong>
                </div>
            .........
         </div>
       </div>
```

word-wrap class is as follows:

```
.word-wrap {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `word-break:break-all`?

Comment: `word-break: break-all` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the text to wrap but are not concerned with the `<strong>` content indenting to another column, you should change your `.word-wrap` class to contain `word-break: break-all;` (and that's all you need):

```
.word-wrap {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

And then enclose your elements with the `.form-group` class (you need to use `.control-label` for your label):

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="text-muted">Employer Information</h4>
            <div class="form-inline word-wrap">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label label-normalWeight">Name</label>
                    <strong class="word-wrap"><bean:write name="myform" property="name" /></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        .........
     </div>
 </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/ST1AlByo4g

However, if you want the entire contents of `<strong>` indented, you are better off creating another set of columns - and then apply `.word-wrap` class to the `<strong>` element or a wrapper:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="text-muted">Employer Information</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
        <label class="control-label label-normalWeight">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <strong class="word-wrap"><bean:write name="myform" property="name" /></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/JLnvtz9o4i

Comment: both the bootplys dont work unfortunately. The long string is coming under Name label which i dont want.

Comment: Sorry, my 2nd bootply was a dupe of the first. Try it again or here: http://www.bootply.com/JLnvtz9o4i

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4 class="text-muted">Employer Information</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="your_id_here">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your_id_here">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- more fields -->      
  </form>
</div>
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/lEpSOZ0TDh).

If you decide to stay with `<strong>`, just add `form-control` class to it and it shall align properly.

Answer (score 0):

If `word-break: break-all` or `word-wrap:break-word` doesn't work, probably your `white-space`  is set to `nowrap`.

Try setting:

`white-space:normal;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    dsfdsfdsfdfdsfASSs
  </div>

</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/KK1MlNLy5V

Comment: doesnt work for long string, see: bootply.com/oEoMeXDQus